# UI does not recognize functions that has default parameters

Tags: unity-game-engine

Seems that for some reasons, Unity UI does not like to have functions that use default parameters

```
public void PrintButtonName(GameObject go, string button_pressed = "none")
{
    if (button_pressed != "none")
        Debug.Log(go.name);

}
```

This won't be displayed in a button click event, in the editor.
If I remove the default value, the editor can "see" the function again, and you can use it.

Why is that? Is this a bug? I need to use an optional parameter, but I can't since the onClick won't see that function with the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assigning `UI` callback functions from Unity Editor is very **limited**. When Unity `UI` came out, you couldn't call function with **more** than **1** parameter from the **Editor**. I still think that this **restriction** still applies now.

The solution is to do this through code.

```
public Button newbiezButton; //Drag button to here from Editor


void OnEnable() (){
//Add listener
 newbiezButton.onClick.AddListener(() => PrintButtonName(yourGameObj, yourString));
}

public void PrintButtonName(GameObject go, string button_pressed = "none")
{
    if (button_pressed != "none")
        Debug.Log(go.name);

}

public void OnDisable(){
//Remove listener
 newbiezButton.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So it is a limitation of the system itself. It is really disappointing that you are forced to use one parameter, unless you write another function. Mostly it add complexity to the code, which in turn increase the chances to mess up something. Thanks again for the explanation!

Comment: No problem. I noticed that you are using Editor for your callback functions in your other questions. **Switch** to code because it does not have limitations. Editor has many limitations you will likely encounter, that I did not mention here.